# AVPlayerViewController Play Icon Removed in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, avkit

In previous versions of iOS, loading AVPlayerViewController (as well as SwiftUI VideoPlayer) with a video would display the first frame and include a play icon in the center but this has gone away in iOS 16. I've been relying on that UI element as an affordance for "There's a video here, tap it".

Plus, now tapping the video shows the playback controls over the video for a few seconds instead of just starting playback.

Does anyone know if:

- There's a property or configuration option to show the play icon?
- I should be providing my own play icon overlay placed over the video manually?
- This is a bug in iOS 16?

[image: iOS 15.5 simulator with play icon, iOS 16 missing play icon]

Comment: Im having the same problem in iOS 16, works fine in iOS 15. For me if I have the VideoPlayer in a TabView, if I hide the TabView controls it seems to also hide the VideoPlayer controls. I believe its an iOS 16 issue.

Comment: Working with `AVPlayer` on simulator is tricky, does it behave the same on real device?

Comment: Same on our live app for iOS 16 devices. Play button is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift UI need to use

```
CustomVideoPlayer()
    .compositingGroup() // Mandatory 


struct CustomVideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

 var player: AVPlayer

 func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
     
     let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
     controller.player = player
     return controller

 }

 func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) {
 }
```

}

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to the problem of the system provided play icon overlay.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33089336)

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think a work around for this issue can be adding

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    avPlayerViewController.setValue(false, forKey: "canHidePlaybackControls")
}
```

and changing it back after one second.
So the code will look like something like this:

```
let avPlayer: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: newURL)
avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
if let avPlayerViewController = avPlayerViewController {
    avPlayerViewController.delegate = self
    avPlayerViewController.player = avPlayer
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        avPlayerViewController.setValue(false, forKey: "canHidePlaybackControls")
    }
    addChild(avPlayerViewController)
    view.addSubview(avPlayerViewController.view)
}
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
        self.avPlayerViewController?.setValue(true, forKey: "canHidePlaybackControls")
    })
}
```

The downside of using this work around is that you'll be using private api calls which can result in your app being rejected by Apple.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to add the `AVPlayerViewController` as a child view controller of your own view controller like this as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758932/1534401):

Swift:

```
addChild(playerController)
```

Objective-C:

```
[self addChildViewController:playerController];
```

Comment: The demo app used for the screenshots adds the child view controller in this way, so it seems to not seem to fix the situation.